# MKTIME always return -1 (Window10_64bit / MSVS2019 / C++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-10, mktime

I have problem..
I can not understand why Function MKTIME always return -1

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

    int main() {
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    struct tm today;

    localtime_s(&today, &now);
    today.tm_year += 1900;
    today.tm_mon += 1;
    time_t t_today = mktime(&today);

    printf("%ld", (long)t_today);

    return 0;
}
```

t_today is -1

Comment: Please read [the documenation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm) for what the year value should be.

Comment: Are you really trying to get to the year 3921 or is it simply a misunderstanding of expected values for `tm_year`?

Answer (score 1):

`mktime` can deal with only upto the year 3000. Adding 1900 to `today.tm_year` will exceed this limit. (1970 + 1900 = 3870) Try smaller offset.

References:

- [localtime_s, _localtime32_s, _localtime64_s | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/localtime-s-localtime32-s-localtime64-s?view=msvc-160)
- [mktime, _mktime32, _mktime64 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/mktime-mktime32-mktime64?view=msvc-160)

Comment: Typo in math. Target year would be 2021 + 1900.

Comment: @SergeyA It need not be. You can modify the clock setting or use [RunAsDate](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/run_as_date.html) for testing.

Comment: Sure thing, but 1970 is just random number, why are you using it?

Comment: @SergeyA It is the origin of time counting by `time_t`.

Comment: But why would it be the value of `tm_year` right after a call to `localtime_s` is unclear. I believe, 2021 (why not necessarily correct due to possible options you mentioned above) is a safer bet and makes a cleaner example.

Comment: The question is asked today. Today is 2021, not 1970. No need to confuse the poor soul even more.